# JS to load CSS files based on local storage values?

Tags: html, css, arrays

So, I have two different .css files, one is default and the other one specifies the dark theme.

So, if my `<head>` contains a:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/file/default.css" type="text/css">
```

early enough, before any `<script>`, then everything works fine; network logging shows that the .css file loads right after the main document.

Things get nasty when I try to use a script to determine the css file dynamically:

```js
const link = document.createElement('link');
const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';

function setTheme(thm) {
  link.href = 'path/to/file/' + thm + '.css';
  localStorage.setItem('theme', thm);
}

if (theme) {
  setTheme(theme);
} else {
  setTheme('default');
}

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

In that case, network logs show that the .css file whose path is returned by the script loads at a much later stage. This results in a FOUC where one of the icons (inserted as `<svg>` code with a `<use>` tag) flashes briefly without style before content is rendered appropriately.

Inspection reveals that the `<link>` generated by this script is inserted into the DOM tree right after the script itself. The script, in turn, is placed very early in the `<head>`, right after the metadata, and is provided within a `<script></script>` tag pair rather than loaded with `src`. however, when rendered by the browser, the script is repositioned to below a few other scripts, some of which load after external sources.

What I would like to be able to do is to implement such dynamic stylesheet link that, when the page is loading, behaves like a statically coded link would, i.e., makes the .css file load as early as possible.

I have tried setting the `body` to `display: none;` in CSS, then reversing the change with JS by doing so:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  if (theme) {
    setTheme(theme);
  } else {
    setTheme('default');
  }
});
```

This, obviosly, only resulted on a FOUC before everything disappears to reappear again.

Right now, I can only think of a solution that is basically the stupidest hack imaginable:

1. Add:

```css
body {
  display: none;
}
```

to the default .css file.

2. Load the file by starting `<head>` with a `<link>` to it.
3. Instead of creating a link, capture it with a selector (by id, by css, whatever) in JS.
4. If localStorage has a value `'dark'` for `'theme'`, alter the link.
5. Add an event listener of some sort to change the `display` property once the css file has loaded.

I do not like this approach because it is certainly not an elegant solution, and that's not even accounting for the fact that it will force CSS files to be reloaded rather than load the right CSS files from the start.

Another solution I am thinking about is to move all different values in CSS files to variables and add a `<body>` attribute:

```css
:root {
--background-color: black;
--text-color: white;
}

[theme="dark"]{
--background-color: white;
--text-color: black;
}
```

However, there are several dozens of color-related variables across multiple files, so doing so would be cumbersome to say the least.

What are the good options here?

**UPD**: apparently the issue disappears if, while monitoring the network, I disable cache. So the FOUC with a single inline `<svg>` happens when that particular icon is cached.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a loader with some timer so that the page render only when the styles are applied. Something like this:

```
  let loadingStyles = true;
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('This will run after 1 second!');
    loadingStyles = false;
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).